# How to add dynamic select menu in search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus?view=comments) and successfully able to display countries and cities as dynamic select menu to choose the country and city on adding new profile. I have created a controller "**search_controller.rb**" with index action and a view "**index.html.erb**" in app/views/search. Now i want to create a search form in app/views/search/index.html.erb which have

1. Autocomplete text field to search by profile's subjects (almost 400 subjects in this table)
2. Country and city dynamic select menu to search by profile's country and city.

**app/model/profile.rb**

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :subjects, through: :categorizations

belongs_to :country
belongs_to :city
```

**app/model/subject.rb**

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :profiles, through: :categorizations
```

**app/model/categorization.rb**

```
belongs_to :profile
belongs_to :subject
```

**app/model/country.rb**

```
has_many :cities
has_many :profiles
```

**app/model/city.rb**

```
belongs_to :country
has_many :profiles
```

**app/views/profiles/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :country_id %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/profiles.js.coffee**

```
$('#profile_city_id').parent().hide()
cities = $('#profile_city_id').html()
$('#profile_country_id').change ->
country = $('#profile_country_id :selected').text()
escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
options = $(cities).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_country}']").html()
if options
  $('#profile_city_id').html(options)
  $('#profile_city_id').parent().show()
else
  $('#profile_city_id').empty()
  $('#profile_city_id').parent().hide()
```

Comment: For those looking at this and using the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised) as an aid there is a revised version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution with `sunspot-solr` for search and `twitter-typeahead-rails` for autocomplete. after adding searchable block in model i used following code for my app. I loaded my subjects list in local storage by twitter typeahead because it will not change but you can use json if you need.

**app/controller/search_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @search = Profile.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    with(:city_id, params[:city]) if params[:city].present?
  end
  @profiles = @search.results
end
```

**app/views/search/index.html.erb**

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'typeahead' %>
<div class="field">
  <%= select_tag :country, options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :name, params[:country]), include_blank: true %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= select_tag :city, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Country.order(:name), :cities, :name, :id, :name, params[:city]), include_blank: true %>
</div>
<%= submit_tag "search", :name => nil, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/profiles.js.coffee**

```
$('#city').parent().hide()
cities = $('#city').html()
$('#country').change ->
  country = $('#country :selected').text()
  escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
  options = $(cities).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_country}']").html()
  if options
    $('#city').html(options)
    $('#city').parent().show()
  else
    $('#city').empty()
    $('#city').parent().hide()

$('.typeahead').typeahead({                                
  local: ["3D Design", "Architecture", "Chemical engineering", ...]
  limit: 10                                                                   
});
```