# Rails 3.2.12 select second element in a form dependant on first collection_select's choice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Venue and an Event Model.

Venue `has_many :events` and Event `belongs_to :venue`.

My Venue's have a `:venue_name` and a `:address`.

My Event's hava an arrangement of attributes and both `:venue_name` and a `:address` also.

When creating a new Event I have used a collection select like so:

`<%= f.label :venue_name %>

<%= f.collection_select(:venue_name, Venue.order(:id), :venue_name, :venue_name) %>`

to set the Event's `:venue_name` with an already existing Venue.

next I have used a similar approach to set the Event's address, by pulling it from an existing Venue like so:

`<%= f.label :address %>

    <%= f.collection_select(:address, Venue.order(:id), :address, :venue_name) %>`

I would like it to recognize the first selection and be able to automatically select the same Venue's `:address` so I can set this behind the scenes and not force the user to select two drop downs for the same Venue's information.

Comment: here is my detailed answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282071/how-to-add-dynamic-select-menu-in-search-form of dynamic select list.

Comment: Not quite what I was trying to accomplish. But I think I will be able to use this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking over the web, and asking some friends of mine who are better with rails than I am, I came to a none Javascript solution that fixes my problem perfectly.

I removed the `:venue_name` and `:address.` from the Event's model.

I then used a `collection_select` that uses Event's `:venue_id` from the `belongs_to` relationship I've setup.

In the create method of the Event I added and edited the following lines to use this during the creation of a new Event:

`@venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])`

`@event = @venue.events.build(params[:event])`

So now when an Event is created it is built using the Venue's `:name` and `:address`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to manage this this type of functionality.

One way is to set up an onChange event for when the venue is selected.  Rails does not have a helper to create these for individual form elements, but a jQuery selector should work fine.  This trigger could either call your Rails app to get a partial that has the address collection for the venue. Or, you can store all of the possible venue addresses in a hidden div and update the content for this selector once the venue has been selected.

This [Rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised) should cover the concepts.

Comment: I was able to rework my event's creation method to achieve the saving of name and address via the venue's params.